# JPA Hibernate Many to Many NestedServletException issue

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

I'm getting this error when I add query for jobs with ids, add them to the jobs set in Employee entity and saves the Employee enitity

```
        2020-02-29 18:01:53.689  WARN 18280 --- [nio-8083-exec-2] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError]
    2020-02-29 18:01:53.692  WARN 18280 --- [nio-8083-exec-2] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@52efd6dc<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@690866176 wrapping Result set representing update count of 2>
    2020-02-29 18:01:53.692  WARN 18280 --- [nio-8083-exec-2] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@4d7d18da<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@2035306242 wrapping Result set representing update count of -1>....
    .....
```

Employee Entity

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Fetch(value= FetchMode.SELECT)
@JoinTable(name = "employees_jobs",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "job_id"))
```

Job Entity

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "jobs")
private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<>();
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved! It was Lombok causing the issue. I removed @Data annotation and added

```
@ToString(exclude = "listName")
```

on top of the entity class. ToString method generated by Lombok is the reason for stackoverflow error